# Map other categories in pandas dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe, **combined_copy** which has a column, *job_industry_category* with multiple categories. I want to use a mapping function to restrict these categories to the top 3 by distribution, the rest form one other category. I intend to use numeric digits as follows:

`combined_copy['job_industry_category'].map({'Manufacturing' : 0, 'Financial Services' : 1, 'Health' : 2})`

I need help on how to map all the other remaining categories into a class 3, as one category.

The list of all categories in this column is as follows:
['Manufacturing', 'Financial Services', 'Not Specified',
'Health', 'Retail', 'Property', 'IT', 'Entertainment',
'Argiculture', 'Telecommunications']

I have tried using the *na_action* argument:

`combined_copy['job_industry_category'].map({'Manufacturing' : 0, 'Financial Services' : 1, 'Health' : 2}, na_action={None : 3})`

but the other category appears as NaNs. Please kindly assist.

Comment: [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use mapping function

```
>>> def com_map(x):
...     if x=='Manufacturing':
...             return 0
...     else:
...             return 3
...
```

inside map function

```
df['j_i_c'].map(com_map)
```